# Oscillation of a continuous curve

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, take $p, q \in \mathbb R^n$ with $d(p,q) > 1$. Take $B_1(p)$ (for simplicity, just call it $B$) and suppose $\gamma$ is a continuous curve between $p,q$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$.

The curve may bounce back and forth between the interior and outside of $B$ (along $\partial B$, and is it correct that the number of times the curve leaves outside the ball is finite? I am almost certain yes due to the compactness of $[0,1]$, but not sure how to prove it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - for example the curve could be something like
$$ \gamma(t) = \begin{cases} \begin{bmatrix}2t\\0\end{bmatrix} & \text{for }t\le 1/2 \\
\Bigl(1+(2t-1)\sin\bigl(\dfrac1{2t-1}\bigr)\Bigr)\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2t-1) \\ \sin (2t-1)\end{bmatrix} & \text{for }t > 1/2 \end{cases}$$